# check if record exists in php array and act upon result

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to do the following in php.

I have two array as follows:

```
$newitems = "id","name","quantity";
$olditems = "id","name","quantity";
```

both contain a list of articles.

What I would like to do:

loop trough the items in `$newitems` and compare them with the items in `$olditems`. Based on the results do the following action:

- `If item is in $newitems AND in $olditems` --> Run update query.
- `If item is in $newitems AND NOT in $olditems` --> Run insert query.
- `If item is NOT in $newitems and IS in $olditems` --> Run delete query.

Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: The `array_intersect()` and `array_difference()` functions are useful for this.

Comment: didn't know where to begin. but i will look at array_intersect() and array_difference() and post the results to help others. thnx.

Comment: You can also just use loops with `in_array()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If item is in $newitems AND in $olditems --> Run update query.

```
$toUpdate = array_intersect($newitems, $olditems);
```

> If item is in $newitems AND NOT in $olditems --> Run insert query.

```
$toInsert = array_diff($newitems, $olditems);
```

> If item is NOT in $newitems and IS in $olditems --> Run delete query.

```
$toDelete = array_diff($olditems, $newitems);
```

Then, you can loop through each of these arrays and perform the corresponding operations.

For more information, see the docs for [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).